# Почему вместо text я получаю None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

У меня есть вот такая таблица

```
<yml_catalog date="2021-01-08 05:00:24">
<shop>
<name>ISSA PLUS</name>
<company>ISSA PLUS</company>
<url>https://issaplus.com/</url>

<currencies>
<currency id="RUB" rate="0.3500000000"/>
<currency id="UAH" rate="1.0000000000"/>
<currency id="USD" rate="30.0000000000"/>
</currencies>

<categories>
<category id="25" parentId="19">Платья</category>
<category id="28" parentId="19">Юбки</category>
</categories>


<offers>
<offer available="true" group_id="1245" id="6549">
<url>https://issaplus.com/plate-417-417_print</url>
<price>405</price>
<old_price>675</old_price>
<currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
<picture>https://issaplus.com/wa-data/public/shop/products/45/12/1245/images/334/334.602x0.jpg</picture>
<picture>https://issaplus.com/wa-data/public/shop/products/45/12/1245/images/335/335.602x0.jpg</picture>
<name>Платья ISSA PLUS 417  XS принт</name>
<description><![CDATA[<p>Стильное платье выполнено из натурального трикотажа в яркой цветочной расцветке. Горловина – округлая. Сзади потайная молния. Длина платья макси. </p>]]></description>
<vendor>ISSA PLUS</vendor>
<vendorCode>417_принт</vendorCode>
<categoryId>25</categoryId>
<param name="Стиль">Вечерний</param>
<param name="Вид">Платья</param>
<param name="Размер">XS</param>
<param name="Цвет">принт</param>
<param name="Коллекция">Happy Day</param>
<param name="Состав">95% коттон, 5% эластан</param>
<param name="Материал">Трикотаж</param>
<param name="Замеры">Грудь: S(80), M(82),L(84), талия: S (70), M(72),L(74), бедра:S(90,M(92),L(94), длина - 78. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.,Грудь: S(90), M(92),L(94), талия: S (80), M(82),L(84), бедра:S(100),M(102),L(104), длина - 84. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.</param>
</offer>

<offer available="true" group_id="1329" id="6955">
<url>https://issaplus.com/plate-422-422_korallovyy</url>
<price>210</price>
<old_price>300</old_price>
<currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
<picture>https://issaplus.com/wa-data/public/shop/products/29/13/1329/images/538/538.602x0.jpg</picture>
<picture>https://issaplus.com/wa-data/public/shop/products/29/13/1329/images/539/539.602x0.jpg</picture>
<picture>https://issaplus.com/wa-data/public/shop/products/29/13/1329/images/540/540.602x0.jpg</picture>
<name>Платья ISSA PLUS 422  M коралловый</name>
<description><![CDATA[<p>Платье выполнено из легкой ткани. Горловина округлая. Сзади оригинальный вырез. Длина макси.</p>]]></description>
<vendor>ISSA PLUS</vendor>
<vendorCode>422_коралловый</vendorCode>
<categoryId>25</categoryId>
<param name="Стиль">Вечерний</param>
<param name="Вид">Платья</param>
<param name="Размер">M</param>
<param name="Цвет">коралловый</param>
<param name="Коллекция">In City</param>
<param name="Состав">85% полиэстер, 15% эластан</param>
<param name="Материал">Полиэстер</param>
<param name="Замеры">Грудь: S(80), M(82),L(84), талия: S (70), M(72),L(74), бедра:S(90,M(92),L(94), длина - 78. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.,Грудь: S(90), M(92),L(94), талия: S (80), M(82),L(84), бедра:S(100),M(102),L(104), длина - 84. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.</param>
</offer>

</offers>

</shop>

</yml_catalog>
```

И я пытаюсь получить каждый параметр но в строке par.text происходит ошибка он возвращеет мне None

```
res = requests.get(url)
res.encoding = 'utf-8'
tree = html.fromstring(res.text)
for host_ip in tree.xpath("shop/offers/offer"):
    for par in host_ip.xpath("param"):
        par_text = par.text
        par_name = par.attrib['name']
        print(par_text)
        print(par_name)
        print(etree.tostring(par))
```

Почему так происходит?
Параметра encoding у него нет
А когда я превращаю его в строку то он возвращает мне

```
b'<param name="&#x421;&#x442;&#x438;&#x43B;&#x44C;"/>&#1042;&#1077;&#1095;&#1077;&#1088;&#1085;&#1080;&#1081;\n'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `lxml.html` использовал `lxml.etree` и получилось вернуть текст

**Причина в том**, что тег [<param>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/param) является зарегистрированным в [html](/questions/tagged/html) и не может иметь текста. Поэтому, парсить нужно именно [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) парсером, а не [html](/questions/tagged/html)

Пример:

```
from lxml import etree

text = ...

tree = etree.fromstring(text)

for host_ip in tree.xpath("shop/offers/offer"):
    for par in host_ip.xpath("param"):
        print(par.attrib['name'], '->', par.text)
```

```
Стиль -> Вечерний
Вид -> Платья
Размер -> XS
Цвет -> принт
Коллекция -> Happy Day
Состав -> 95% коттон, 5% эластан
Материал -> Трикотаж
Замеры -> Грудь: S(80), M(82),L(84), талия: S (70), M(72),L(74), бедра:S(90,M(92),L(94), длина - 78. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.,Грудь: S(90), M(92),L(94), талия: S (80), M(82),L(84), бедра:S(100),M(102),L(104), длина - 84. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.
Стиль -> Вечерний
Вид -> Платья
Размер -> M
Цвет -> коралловый
Коллекция -> In City
Состав -> 85% полиэстер, 15% эластан
Материал -> Полиэстер
Замеры -> Грудь: S(80), M(82),L(84), талия: S (70), M(72),L(74), бедра:S(90,M(92),L(94), длина - 78. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.,Грудь: S(90), M(92),L(94), талия: S (80), M(82),L(84), бедра:S(100),M(102),L(104), длина - 84. Ткань: Высокой  эластичности.
```

Comment: даже не представляю, как вы догадались

Comment: @JopaBoga, ну попробовал через bs4 распарсить -- получилось (указал `xml`) в качестве парсера, после повторил, но попробовал через `lxml` и `html.parser` и bs4 для тех элементов не вернул значения как у автора вопроса, причем выведя элементы увидел, что у них не было текстового содержимого, только атрибут `name`. Подумал, что причина в парсере `html`, погуглил проблемный тег и увидел его формат, дошло, что тег не может иметь текст :)